# How to prevent component from overlapping content?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have created an angular component called **toolbar** and applied the following CSS to it.

```
position: fixed;
z-index: 999;
height: 100px;
```

I used position to fix my toolbar to the page whenever I scroll the page. I used z-index to display the toolbar over all other elements on the page.

This makes up for an individual element that I used in the app.component.html.

My problem is, when creating a page using a new component, if I navigate to said page, the **'newcomponent works!'** does not show up because the toolbar overlaps it.

I wish to make my toolbar fixed in a way that if I had any new element, whatever element I display, it appears right under the toolbar instead of underneath it.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

What could help you is `position: sticky;` which is exactly what you're asking for.

Here is an example (you need to specify the position, for example `top: 0` for `position: sticky` to take effect):

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.toolbar {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.contents {
  height: 5000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="toolbar">xyz</div>
<div class="contents">
  <div>contents</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The toolbar no longer scrolls with, when I scroll the page.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Also, you need to specify `top: 0` (or any other value) for `position: sticky` to work.

Comment: I added `top: 0 ` and it still didn't work. Tried it with Chrome as well as Safari. Same result.

Comment: If you're using Safari, you should also specify the `position` CSS property to be of value `-webkit-sticky`. (Note that the processor should automatically do this for you)

Comment: Yes, your code snippet works great! Still doesn't work locally. Thanks for your help though!